# javascript change class doesn't perform the event

Tags: javascript, jquery, onclick

I am trying to make a ajax load of a table. I have 2 buttons "Free Cars", "Reservations". When click "Free Cars" load all info from database and on click of tr it redirects to an url.

```
$('.cars_table').on('click', 'tr', function() {
        var values = $(this).find('td').map(function() {
            return $(this).text();
        });
        var startdate = $('input[name$="startdate"]').val();
        var starttime = $('input[name$="starttime"]').val();
        var enddate = $('input[name$="enddate"]').val();
        var endtime = $('input[name$="endtime"]').val();
        window.location.href = 'rental/create/' + values[0] + '~' + startdate + ' ' + starttime + '~' + enddate + ' ' + endtime + '';
    });
```

Then on click of "Reservations" I change the class of tbody :

```
$('#cars_table').removeClass('cars_table').addClass('res_made');
```

But it doesn't perform the script which

```
 $('.res_made').on('click', 'tr', function() {
        var values = $(this).find('td').map(function() {
            return $(this).text();
        });
        var startdate = $('input[name$="startdate"]').val();
        var starttime = $('input[name$="starttime"]').val();
        var enddate = $('input[name$="enddate"]').val();
        var endtime = $('input[name$="endtime"]').val();
        window.location.href = 'reservations/create/' + values[0] + '~' + startdate + ' ' + starttime + '~' + enddate + ' ' + endtime + '';
    });
```

Instead it performs the first script and on click of reservations rows it goes to the .cars_table redirect url. With inspect element it shows that the class has changed but then it doesnt performs the script for that class. What is happening?

Answer (score 0):

Event bindings happen on the DOM elements themselves. If you try to bind an event on all `.res_made` elements before there are any elements with this class, no events will be bound.

To solve your problem, you could bind your event once and check inside the handler which class is currently set.

Answer (score 0):

You should dynamically bind the `click` events, because the class of the table can dynamically change. So to make it work in your case, you should change your javascript to the following:

```
$(document).on('click', '.cars_table tr', function() {
        var values = $(this).find('td').map(function() {
            return $(this).text();
        });
        var startdate = $('input[name$="startdate"]').val();
        var starttime = $('input[name$="starttime"]').val();
        var enddate = $('input[name$="enddate"]').val();
        var endtime = $('input[name$="endtime"]').val();
        window.location.href = 'rental/create/' + values[0] + '~' + startdate + ' ' + starttime + '~' + enddate + ' ' + endtime + '';
    });

$(document).on('click', '.res_made tr', function() {
        var values = $(this).find('td').map(function() {
            return $(this).text();
        });
        var startdate = $('input[name$="startdate"]').val();
        var starttime = $('input[name$="starttime"]').val();
        var enddate = $('input[name$="enddate"]').val();
        var endtime = $('input[name$="endtime"]').val();
        window.location.href = 'reservations/create/' + values[0] + '~' + startdate + ' ' + starttime + '~' + enddate + ' ' + endtime + '';
    });
```

See this [FIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/fkpne4gx/) for an example. Of course, as an alternative, you could also bind the event once and check for the class of the table in the event handler, like Martin Denk suggested.